# What type of controls don't show up in Spy++/Inspect?

Tags: winapi, windows

We are working on an Windows Desktop application that pulls values from other controls on other applications.  What we have works great for most desktop applications.  I have noticed that some controls don't show up in inspect and Spy++.  For example, in GP 2015 client only a handful of the controls are addressable in Spy++ and Inspect.  The large majority wont show in the repective tree in Spy++ or Inspect.  What type of controls don't show in Inspect and for extra credit, how can we talk to them?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 6):

Spy++ only works with controls that have an `HWND` associated with them.

Inspect only works with controls that are exposed to [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) via the [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx), [`IUIAutomation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406.aspx), and other related interfaces.

So, any **custom-made non-windowed non-automatable control** will not appear in either tool. Such controls are not available to the outside world, so you cannot communicate with them, or manipulate them. Only the owning app can, since only it has knowledge of what they are and how to interact with them.

Comment: Based on my experience working on a Windows automated test tool some years ago, Microsoft applications are some of the worst offenders about that, Office in particular. Microsoft loves to ignore their own standards and advice and build custom controls that defy reverse engineering.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I just fired up Word 2013 and Excel 2013, and looked around using the Inspect.exe tool. Although I didn't perform in-depth research, I wasn't able to find even a single element, that wasn't exposed through the accessible tree. I guess your blunt statement is as wrong as if I claimed, that Microsoft Office is one of the prime examples of how to do accessibility. With respect to somewhat current releases, this latter statement may even be true.

Comment: @IInspectable Admittedly, I never used that tool with the most recent releases of Office, so feel free to amend my comment to read that it _used to be_ one of the worst offenders. However, I won't amend my statement that Microsoft loves to ignore their own standards.

Comment: @CareyGregory: *"Microsoft loves to ignore their own standards."* - I'm sure you could say the same about IBM, or Apple. Leaving aside, that your statement wasn't even true, singling out Microsoft for no apparent reason is fairly random, and it seems like the only motivation for your comment was to earn a couple of cheap laughs.

Comment: @IInspectable It wasn't random at all, but do you always get this worked up about random comments? Give it a rest already.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  The HWND/Spy++, Automation/Inspect stuff I was already aware of.  Thanks for the reinforcement.  Its easier to explain to management why it does not work when you have backup.  We have been fighting this for about 10 years...

Comment: The UI in question this time is the UI for Great Plains that does use a custom built UI framework called